# Twitterizer OAuth login for desktop app without web UI

Tags: c#, wpf, twitterizer

I want to write an application which can update an twitter status of an certain twitter account.
The user has to log in to twitter.

I want to make this application with Twitterizer, but since it uses oAuth, the user needs to go to the twitter website to tell twitter that my application is granted access to the user's twitter account.

Because I want to make a very simple twitter application for people who are not really even expert with computers, I don't really want that process.

Is there any option to automate the web UI of the oAuth process? Or an option to don't use that web UI?

Comment: I think it takes more computer knowledge to tell a username from a password than to choose yes or no.

Comment: It is complicated because you have to open the webbrowser, read the PIN, go back to my app, put in the PIN. It is easier only to put in you username and password.

Comment: Do you expect people to trust you to know their login&pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of OAuth is to ensure that the user is aware that they are granting a 3rd party access to their account. If OAuth allowed the process to be automated, it would undermine the very reason it exists.

One way around asking the user to copy/paste a PIN, is to use the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class to create a simple webservice that runs on the client's computer. You can create it long enough to listen for the user to be directed back to the callback url and capture the values needed. I've demonstrated this technique [on my blog](http://www.ricky-dev.com/2010/07/oauth-trick/).

Just as commentary: to say "but since [Twitterizer] uses oAuth" insinuates that it was my design decision (I'm Twitterizer author), where it is really the security protocol required to interact with the Twitter API. Every Twitter library requires the use of OAuth.